# How to print individual key and value from json array after converting from csv to json in NodeJS and Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I am a fresher and new to Javascript and Typescript, I am learning in the office. I have a csv file and I am able to parse the CSV file using this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser. After parsing, I am getting the array of json key and values. I provide below the output.

```
[ { 'PURCHASE DATE': '2016-04-03',
    'CANDY PURCHASED': '1000',
    'CASH PAID': '10000.11',
    'BUYER NAME': 'Charlie Kelly' },
  { 'PURCHASE DATE': '2017-11-14',
    'CANDY PURCHASED': '1000',
    'CASH PAID': '12000.22',
    'BUYER NAME': 'Frank Reynolds' },
  { 'PURCHASE DATE': '2018-01-20',
    'CANDY PURCHASED': '2000',
    'CASH PAID': '40000.33',
    'BUYER NAME': 'Frank Reynolds' },
  { 'PURCHASE DATE': '2018-03-20',
    'CANDY PURCHASED': '2000',
    'CASH PAID': '40000.44',
    'BUYER NAME': 'Mac' },
  { 'PURCHASE DATE': '2019-01-02',
    'CANDY PURCHASED': '2000',
    'CASH PAID': '50000.55',
    'BUYER NAME': 'Sweet Dee' },
  { 'PURCHASE DATE': '2019-01-02',
    'CANDY PURCHASED': '1500',
    'CASH PAID': '13500.66',
    'BUYER NAME': 'Dennis Reynolds' } ]
```

Now my requirement is to print only the buyer name from the above json object.

I tried using the following code but it is not working.

```
for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            console.log("Printing ===>", results[i].name)
            console.log("Buyer Name ====", JSON.stringify(results[i]))
        }
```

Please help me to solve it. I am writing the code in Typescript file Myparser.ts.

Comment: The key for the buyer name is `"BUYER NAME"`, so you need to use `results["BUYER NAME"]` to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
results.map(result => result['BUYER NAME']).forEach(buyer => console.log(buyer));
```

Please Refer [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: I also did using for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            let obj: any = results[i];
            console.log("=====>",obj['BUYER NAME']);
        }.

Answer (score 1):

```
results.forEach((obj)=>console.log(obj['BUYER NAME']));
```

Comment: Hi Salman, is it possible to use for loop instead of results.forEach to print the buyer name. Please update, I will accept it.

Comment: It is possible to use "for" loop. Both are same but in for loop you need to declare increment variable i , and check condition whether its less than length of array and increment the variable.Instead of doing all this we can use forEach loop.  Check this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp

Answer (score 0):

```js
const results=[ { 'PURCHASE DATE': '2016-04-03',
    'CANDY PURCHASED': '1000',
    'CASH PAID': '10000.11',
    'BUYER NAME': 'Charlie Kelly' },
  { 'PURCHASE DATE': '2017-11-14',
    'CANDY PURCHASED': '1000',
    'CASH PAID': '12000.22',
    'BUYER NAME': 'Frank Reynolds' },
  { 'PURCHASE DATE': '2018-01-20',
    'CANDY PURCHASED': '2000',
    'CASH PAID': '40000.33',
    'BUYER NAME': 'Frank Reynolds' },
  { 'PURCHASE DATE': '2018-03-20',
    'CANDY PURCHASED': '2000',
    'CASH PAID': '40000.44',
    'BUYER NAME': 'Mac' },
  { 'PURCHASE DATE': '2019-01-02',
    'CANDY PURCHASED': '2000',
    'CASH PAID': '50000.55',
    'BUYER NAME': 'Sweet Dee' },
  { 'PURCHASE DATE': '2019-01-02',
    'CANDY PURCHASED': '1500',
    'CASH PAID': '13500.66',
    'BUYER NAME': 'Dennis Reynolds' } ]
    
    results.map(obj=>{
    console.log(obj['BUYER NAME']);
    })
```

As you asked only to print `Buyer Name`
What you did is right. But you cannot fetch multi word String like `results[i].name`